# Shared Access Signature URL returns The requested URL does not represent any resource on the server

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

using my Visual Studio Enterprise subscription, I can create a SAS from a blob.
It looks like this. I created this from console, so quite confident about it

```
https://[mystorageaccounthere].blob.core.windows.net/[thecontainernamehere]?sp=r&st=2022-02-02T21:25:10Z&se=2022-02-03T05:25:10Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=[the signtaure]
```

Then I try out a sample taken from Azure Storage samples to get the properties.

```
Uri mySASUri = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SAS_URL"));
BlobServiceClient service = new BlobServiceClient(mySASUri);
await service.GetPropertiesAsync();
```

Result is an exception

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.RequestFailedException: The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.
```

any ideas

Thanks to all who look into this

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SAS URL. Do obfuscate the account name and sig portion before sharing.

Comment: Thanks @GauravMantri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you are using an incorrect type of SAS token (URL). You are creating a SAS token on the container which is a [`Service SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas) kind of token which will only work on the container (or blob) for which The SAS token is acquired.

Considering [`BlobServiceClient.GetPropertiesAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobserviceclient.getpropertiesasync?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-blobserviceclient-getpropertiesasync(system-threading-cancellationtoken)) is an account level operation, you would need to create an [`Account SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) token and use that to perform this operation.

Please create an Account SAS URL with at least `read` permission and use that in your code and you should not get this error.